# C# Text Editor without WPF?

Tags: c#, file, text, editor

Okay. I understand that I don't ask the right question and that's why I ask my pardon. I will try to explain my problem again. I have a task. It says that my Program must create a text file and then, while it is running on background I must open the created text file manually, write something(random text) and then write(on the same line) "@"-that is a sign after which I write some of those functions :  "@save" - that creates new text file and move the random text form the first text file to the second one after i manually close the first text file, "@open" - takes the saved text form the new created file and display it in the first one. I have no better explanation and also i don't want the whole code but i started only with creating text file and don't know how to move forward.....

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are asking. Are you asking us how to make a text editor?

Comment: You need to add a lot of detail.  Notepad is already a text editor, so your work is done,

Comment: What do you want with NotePad?? You can write a text editor, which is an excellent exercise or you could learn about controlling other programs. But neither without understanding what you really want!

Comment: SO is a question and answer site and you haven't asked a question. Are you trying to create a text file in C#? Investigate [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes...i tried SreamWriter , but i must not write in the Console of Visual studio...and this is where i stuck....no idea how to proceed...now i am trying to write a Checker if the file is modified from the last time used and if it is modified to check the sting in the file if there are keywords like ""save"" and so on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Process.Start("notepad.exe", filePath);
```

this works

Comment: yes, but just to open the notepad...i want my program to open the notepad file and turn the empty text file into a text editor...thank you for your comment